# How to apply formatting to particular font type in MS word 2007

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-word, formatting

I have word document with 100 pages.

Now in that Doc i have different language font in one line and then English translation in other line.

Now i want to format the language font only e.g i want to change the color that font.

How can do that without changing color of English font. I don't want to do manually by selecting each line and apply setting

Comment: Are the 2 different lines in different Word Styles?

Comment: Yes , frist line different font(my language font) and second line Arial , then third line lnaguage font and fourth line Arial and so on

Comment: Yes, but is that a direct font application or is it an actual Word Style (i.e. Normal, Heading 1 etc etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing you mean you have different fonts for different languages, if that is the case you can do following

- open "Find and replace" window
- select Replace tab
- click on More button
- click in Find edit field
- at the bottom of the form in Replace section click Format and select Font
- in Font window enter the font you want to change (e.g. Arial) and click OK
- click in Replace edit field
- select Format -> Font again but this time just select the new color and click OK
- click Replace all

Comment: I did not know you could do find and replace on formatting - very cool :)

Comment: ha ha wow that worked perfectly , Didn't knew whether it was actually possible or not but just posted here. But excellent stuff